# When setting JAVA_HOME does it need to be in capitals and have an underscore

Tags: java

When setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable, does it necessarily need to be in that exact format?

Comment: yes and no...depends upon the application that's using it...

Comment: dido this is an environment variable and the environment in question is the OS.  So where it is defined is dependent not on the application but on the machine.  Stil see my answer below there is no reason not to always define it this way.  Others should have pointed out that you define it in files like .bash .cshrc files on unix based systems including mac, and in System Properties in windows.

Comment: For which app are you setting the JAVA_HOME?  An IDE, a WebServer? Your own app?  In general you define it once at the OS level if it was not already done for you at installation.  It is then referenced in config files.

Comment: So we need to know if you need to define it or reference it? Perhaps you need to do both.

Answer (score 2):

It *definitely* needs to have an underscore–it's an identifier, and underscores aren't randomly ignored.

It *should* be all upper-case, although some degenerate systems might decide to either ignore case, or look up something lower-cased if it can't find it upper-cased. Certainly not behavior to depend on.

This just seems like a weird question to ask, though.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it needs to be in that exact format.

For definition, see [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~gbenson/zero-11-hotspot/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp-.html), line 2086, or [here](http://code.google.com/p/needle/source/browse/src/os/windows/vm/os_windows.cpp?r=1e637defdda69004d10472d3f54f6b29b1feac64#1718).

Comment: can you pls give an explanation why?

Comment: @dido Because it's the name of a variable--what kind of explanation are you looking for? That's the name of the variable.

Comment: i know it's the name of the variable, but where is that variable defined

Comment: @dido - inside the jvm.  added link.

Comment: @dido Where is it *defined*, or *used*? It's *defined* wherever you define it, a batch file, Windows config, shell init script, command line, etc. It's *used* by anything that uses it.

Comment: @jtahiborn there are three common ways in which we see JAVA_HOME every day.  Definiting it in the OS, and referencing it are the most common.  JVM is not something any of us check on a daily basis.  Saying its defined in the JVM is a bit convoluted for this question.

Comment: @CodeDroid - quite frankly, i misunderstood what the OP was getting at initially, the comments were a bit vague.  i _thought_ the OP was asking why it had to follow the specific naming format, so i was attempting to show the usage of the variable within the jvm.

Comment: @CodeDroid He did well to track down not one but two places where it is defined in JVMs, which after all is the main if not the only reason for setting it at all. I don't see anything 'convoluted' about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it needs to be exactly like that

```
 JAVA_HOME
```

and there is no advantage in it being anything else.  Conventions are there for a reason and its best just to follow them, when there is no benefit to the alternative.

Please note there are three common ways in which JAVA_HOME appears:

1) As a OS Level Definition.
2) It is referenced by the config files of applications like IDE's, Web Servers etc. 
3) build tools like ant, maven etc.

So for a reference to work, it first needs to be defined usually at the OS LEVEL and then referenced in the config file.  Referencing and defining are not the same.

Answer (score -1):

You have to name it EXACTLY like that, unless the code using it, is your own and you're able to change it.

If your code was looking for an environment variable, how would you expect to find it if it wasnt named exactly like the name you were expecting?

Comment: Please explain the downvote, that would be so much more polite.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it should be in Capital letter. Like `JAVA_HOME`. And it is case sensitive. But , the path is not case sensitive.

Comment: The path *is* case-sensitive on Unices.